# Converting String to byte array for hex values

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte, number-systems

I am using a Android Phone to communicate with a BLE device.

The method to send data for the library needs byte[], 
sharing one of the **static example snippet:**

```
 public static final byte dataRequest[] = { 0x23,  0x57,  0x09,  0x03, (byte) 0xD4};
 sendDataToDevice(dataRequest);
```

The data i am receiving from the user is in String, for example

```
String str1 = "D4";
```

now my question is , how to convert this String value (which is actually a hex value in String datatype) to byte, so that i can store these dynamic String values and convert and then insert it into byte[] like ,

```
byte[0] = convertToByte(str1);
```

where byte[0] must store value as 0xD9 or like the format given in static example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use `Integer#parseInt` with a `radix` of `16` (hexadecimal) to convert a `String` to an `int` (which you can then cast to a `byte` and store in your array):

```
String str1 = "D4";
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str1, 16);
System.out.println(b);
```

Output:

```
-44
```

Note: `Byte#parseByte` can't be used in your example, as `Byte#parseByte` uses `Integer#parseInt` internally and parses `D4` as `212`, which is not a valid value for a signed `byte`.